# Evaluating $\iint \limits _R \cot^{-1} \frac y x {\rm d}A$ on $1 \le x^2 + y^2 \le 4, \ 0 \le y \le x$

Tags: calculus, integration

I tried to evaluate
$$\iint \limits _R \cot^{-1} \frac y x {\rm d}A,$$
where $R$ is bounded by $1 \le x^2 + y^2 \le 4$ and $0 \le y \le x$.

How can I complete the solution?

Comment: Please add the link to your image or, better, use MathJax to typeset your formulas.

Comment: @rubik okay. I will

Comment: That's not working. Just add the link, I'll edit the question.

Comment: @rubik here is the problem link http://i.stack.imgur.com/dYVDN.jpg

Comment: Have you studied changes of variables to polar coordinates? This is how it's done.

Comment: @AlexM. Yes I studied it but I couldn't get bounds of$ r$ and $\theta $

Answer (score 1):

Proceed with the change of variables
$$\begin{cases}
x = \rho\cos\theta\\
y = \rho\sin\theta
\end{cases}$$

From the condition $1 \leq x^2 + y^2 \leq 4$ you get, by substitution, $1 \leq \rho \leq 2$. From the second one,
$$0 \leq \rho\sin\theta \leq \rho\cos\theta \implies 0 \leq \tan\theta \leq 1 \implies 0 \leq \theta \leq \frac\pi4.$$

The integral then becomes (don't forget the extra $\rho$):
$$\int_1^2\int_0^{\pi/4}\rho\cot^{-1}\frac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}\mathrm d\theta\mathrm d\rho$$

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to apply Fubini's theorem, and this will lead you to a dead end. Instead, change to polar coordinates: $x = r \cos \alpha, \ y = r \sin \alpha$. In principle, if you had no conditions on $x$ and $y$, $(r, \alpha)$ would have lived in $(0, \infty) \times [0, 2 \pi)$. In this problem, though, you do have restrictions on $x$ and $y$; when you rewrite them in polar coordinates they become

$$\left\{ \begin{array} {ll} 1 \le r^2 \le 4 \\ 0 \le r \sin \alpha \le r \cos \alpha \end{array} \right.$$

which simplifies to

$$\left\{ \begin{array} {ll} 1 \le r \le 2 \\ 0 \le \sin \alpha \le \cos \alpha \end{array} \right. .$$

Let's solve the trigonometric double inequality: first, what are the angles $\alpha \in [0, 2 \pi)$ that have $\sin \alpha \ge 0$? Well, they are precisely $\alpha \in [0, \pi]$. Next, what are the angles $\alpha \in [0, 2 \pi)$ where $\sin \alpha \le \cos \alpha$? Well, you need to know a bit of trigonometry to see that $\alpha \in [0, \frac \pi 4] \cup [\frac {5 \pi} 4, 2 \pi)$. Intersecting the intervals of these solutions you get $\alpha \in [0, \frac \pi 4]$. This shows that you have correctly found $R$, working in Cartesian coordinates. The trouble with these is that the integral is extremely difficult to do with them, but really easy in polar coordinates, as you are going to see.

Note that $\cot^{-1} \frac y x = \cot ^{-1} \tan \alpha = \cot ^{-1} \cot \left( \frac \pi 2 - \alpha \right) = \frac \pi 2 - \alpha$, so the integral transforms into

$$\int \limits _1 ^2 \left( \int \limits _0 ^{\frac \pi 4} \frac \pi 2 - \alpha \ {\rm d} \alpha \right) r \ {\rm d} r = \int \limits _1 ^2 \left( \frac {\pi^2} 8 - \frac {\pi^2} {32} \right) r \ {\rm d} r = \frac {3 \pi^2} {32} \int \limits _1 ^2 r \ {\rm d} r = \frac {3 \pi^2} {32} \frac 3 2 = \color{blue} {\frac {9 \pi^2} {64}} .$$